# Flashing Safari

Tags: macos, safari

I just upgraded to OS X El Capitan and my Safari windows are constantly flashing. I've already re-started my computer, but it's still flashing. It's mostly when something on the page is moving and mainly on constantly moving pages, such as Facebook, Pandora, and Imgur. Is there something I can do to make it stop flashing?

Answer (score 1):

Choose Develop → Show Web Inspector (⌥⌘I) and select [image] Disable paint flashing.

Comment: What are you talking about?